# "Siamo bene" o "Siamo beni"?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, agreement, plural

La parola 'bene' è un aggettivo, e 'noi' è plurale.

Così, quale di questi è corretto?:

- "Siamo bene" o
- "Siamo beni"

Comment: Hello and welcome to Italian.SE! There are various problems here (starting from "La parola bene è un aggettivo"). But first of all, so that we can better help you, what is the concept that you wish to express with this Italian sentence? That you and some other person are doing well and are in good shape?

Comment: «La parola 'bene' è un aggettivo»: butta via il libro, licenzia l'insegnante o disinstalla l'app che te l'ha detto. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bene* is not an adjective. It can be an [adverb](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bene1/) or a [noun](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bene2/) (but only in the sense of a good or a property, or for denoting the abstract quality of *goodness*, see the linked page on the dictionary).

If you're trying to translate “We're well”, then it is *Stiamo bene*, because Italian uses *stare*, not *essere*, in this case.